# Estou estudando sobre python /django e me deparei com uma from e um import chamada "Rating" alguém poderia me explicar para que serve?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, django

```
def show_scoring_average(self):
    from .Rating import Rating   # Gostaria de entender esta linha
    try:
        ratings = Rating.objects.filter(user_rated = self.user).aggregate(Sum('value'), Count('user'))
        if ratings['user__count'] > 0 :
            scoring_average = ratings['value__sum'] / ratings ['user__count']
            scoring_average = round(scoring_average,2)
            return scoring_average
        return 'Sem avaliações'
    except:
        return 'Sem Avaliações'
```

Comment: `**from .Rating import Rating**` está escrito assim mesmo ou voce acrescentou o `*`?

Comment: Eu Acrescentei os **

Comment: Você está importando um modulo chamado Rating e dentro delete pegando o Rating. Então na mesma pasta desse script, provavelmente, tem um arquivo `Rating.py` e dentro dele parece que tem uma classe (model django acho) com o nome `Rating` (algo como `class Rating`).

Comment: dentro desta função chamda show_scoring_average(self): existem um import que poderia ser fora dela... esse importe é de um model... um modelo correspondendo as atribuições do banco de dados... e a um filtro que seleciona um determinado item